# Why can't I browse my BlobStorage within azure synapse?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

I am trying to make an ingestion pipeline from Azure Posgres to Azure Blob storage.

In the destination step i try to browse the folder path but instead get the following error:

[image]

What am I missing?

[Here are the connection configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PobBl.png)

EDIT:

I did create a container in my blob storage account. It then did show the container in the folder structure of the destination step above. But when I choose this container as folder path I still get the same error.

Comment: This is probably the result of permission issue to the blob storage. Please post your linked service (connection) configuration to see what kind of authentication you use.

Comment: I did post the configs and edited the post!

Comment: Any chance this account is configured as ADLS Gen2?

Answer (score 0):

I created copy data tool to copy data from SQL database to blob storage.
I created SQL database dataset for Source:

[image]

Blob storage dataset for sink:

[image]

Selected the table in databse:

[image]

Browsed for blob storage container selected blob container.

[image]

The deployment completed Successfully.

[image]

In my case I was able to browse blob container. Here are my networking of storage account

[image]

And Container Access level:

[image]

According to your situation once check below options carefully:

1. enable public access to the Blob Storage container.
2. If you are using private network access check your Synapse workspace IP address is added to the allowed IP address list for the Blob Storage account.
3. If you are using managed private endpoints to connect Blob Storage, confirm that the private endpoint is properly configured and authorized to access the Blob Storage account.

Comment: The public access to the Blob Storage container was not enabled! Thank you very much!!